# PayPal IPN - using different email for user registration to PayPal Account

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have setup a PayPal IPN for our website and is working correctly however if someone uses a different email address to their PayPal account email address I am unable to match them to the IPN message and mark them as paid.

How have other people got around this issue? I don't particularly want to use time just in case two people are registering at the same time.

--- Resolution: `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $rand ?>" />` inside the form with the custom button. The POST picked this up and sent through to the IPN message.

Comment: You should use the transaction ID, not the email address for payment identification, and **definitely** not the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to either (a) add an invoice ID to the transaction, or (b) add a custom value to the transaction.  Almost all of the PayPal payments products allow for this.  (For example, in PayPal Payments Standard, the parameter name is `invnum` for the invoice ID, or `custom` for the custom value.  In Express Checkout, it's `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM` and `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM`.)  The data is included in the IPN postback, so you can use it to match up with the payment in your records.  The difference between the two is that PayPal will block transactions that use the same invoice ID as a previous transaction (as long as the merchant hasn't turned the setting off for it), whereas the custom value just gets passed through without being checked.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction I used a custom field hidden input field.